# Binding method to an option in a component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm pretty new to Vue and are using a litebox component which I want to customize a bit so the lightbox gallery starts on different images depending on which button is pressed. I have succeeded to solve this by using a click event which I'm binding to an option in the litebox component. Since I am new to Vue. I'm just wondering if this is a good way of solving something like this or if there is a better way?

```
<template>
  <div id>
    <button type="button" @click="show(); start1();">Show Litebox start 1</button>
    <button type="button" @click="show(); start2();">Show Litebox start 2</button>

    <vue-litebox v-if="showLitebox" :startAt="start" :items="images" @close="hide"></vue-litebox>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueLitebox from "vue-litebox";

export default {
  components: { VueLitebox },
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        "https://placekitten.com/400/400",
        "https://placekitten.com/400/401",
        {
          title: "My image title",
          src: "https://placekitten.com/400/402"
        }
      ],
      showLitebox: false,
      start: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    show() {
      this.showLitebox = true;
    },
    hide() {
      this.showLitebox = false;
    },
    start1() {
      this.start = 1
    },
    start2() {
      this.start = 2
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the code on code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9ok4y6lopo?fontsize=12

Comment: The general `@click` approach is good, but the chained methods (using `;`) less so. Why not instead do `show(x)` and then in `show` do `this.start = x` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates should be as logic-free as possible, besides, there is no need to chain methods this way because you can always pass parameters to methods, like this:

```
// in your template
<button
  type="button"
  @click="show(1)"
>
  Show Litebox start 1
</button>

// in methods section
show (start = 1) { // defaults to 1
  this.show = true;
  this.start = start;
}
```

By the way, it seems like v-show would be a better choice than v-if for vue-litebox component ([see documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)).

Comment: thanks for that solution! Actually v-show doesnt really work in this situation for some reason so I need v-if. You can test by changing on code sandbox with opening and closing the different images.